# The passing of time

Tags: cosmology, spacetime, time, universe, big-bang

Did the passing of time come before everything else? As in, how long was there "nothing"? And if we can put a time on that, wouldn't time itself be something? And if so, is time the thing that "always was, always is and always will be"? Will time always exist, even if there was nothing else out there? I feel like it would have too. And is it possible for time and space to be the same thing? Like could time, space, and distance be the same thing?

Comment: Time and space are entirely different things. Their similarity is strictly limited to Lorentz symmetry.

Comment: These are mostly philosophical (or metaphysical) questions which physics cannot answer. Those parts of your question which can be answered have been dealt with already on this site by posts such as [How can something happen when time does not exist?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/24018) and [What's the difference between space and time?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/46112)

Comment: This question has been cross-posted in Philosophy SE and has been answered there : https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/69832/the-passing-of-timeThis

Comment: I didn't mean to ask this question in Philosophy. This is my first time here. However, my question was not answered--I was simply directed to post my question in Physics.